# Assign variable wstring to Char array in C++

Tags: c++, vector, char

I have char array as follows:

```
TCHAR name[256] = L"abc";
```

Also I have another wstring vector as follows,

```
std::vector<std::wstring> nameList;
nameList.push_back(L"cde");
nameList.push_back(L"fgh");
```

I want to assign **nameList** vector first element to **name** array,

Can any one help for that me?

Comment: `char name[256] = L"abc";` should be `wchar_t ...`

Comment: Or why not `std::wstring name;`? Then you should be able to assign `name = nameList[0];`

Comment: Updated the question adding TCHAR. I want to use TCHAR array as according to the existing implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy); `name` is an array with a bound, but it's usage as a function argument decays to a pointer to it's first element, which satisfies the requirements for an output iterator.

So you can:

```
wchar_t name[256] = L"abc";

std::vector<std::wstring> nameList;
nameList.push_back(L"cde");
nameList.push_back(L"fgh");

std::copy(nameList.front().begin(), nameList.front().end(), name);
```

Note that: this will not add any trailing `\0` terminator to the buffer; If you wanted to replace/overwrite `name`, you should as well just use `std::wstring` and save yourself some hassles

Comment: Do you have any idea to add trailing \0 terminator to this buffer without changing the type? Is this ok?
name[nameList.front().length()] = '\0';

Comment: yes it is ... please note that this and my answer assumes that the buffer `name` is large enough

Answer (score 1):

Given your question and the assumption that you must use an array instead of a wstring, your best bet may be to use either `std::copy` or even an old fashioned `memcpy`. However these are dangerous for the following two reasons:

1. If TCHAR is not actually a wchar_t there are likely be to memory errors.
2. If nameList contains a string that is longer than 255 TCHAR characters you will have a buffer overflow.

That said, you can do this safely with the following:

```
if (nameList[0].size() >= 256) {
    throw std::length_error("string too long");
}
std::copy(nameList[0].begin(), nameList[0].end(), name);
name[nameList[0].size()] = TCHAR(0);
```

You could also add a `static_assert` to force a compiler error if TCHAR is not a wchar_t, but it probably isn't necessary as the copy would perform any implicit conversion on a character by character basis.